# Drawing disconnected lines in mayavi calling mlab.plot3d once

Tags: python, 3d, grid, line, mayavi

I've started using mayavi and I am trying to plot a voxel grid. For this I am using mlab.plot3d to plot each line of the grid, what makes the program very slow since the render has to be called for each line. Is there a way to plot all the lines by calling mlab.plot3d just once ? The main problem is that the lines I am plotting are disconnected, if I put one line after the other in the same array, the render is going to plot connections that I don't want. I've tried to connect the two non-connected lines by putting a None between both lines:

```
lines = [0.0, 3.0, None, 0.0, 6.0]
```

But this does not work.

My function to plot the grid line by line can be seen below:

```
def draw_voxel_grid_bbox_translated(voxel_grid, tube_radius=0.01, color=(0,0,0)):
'''
Draw a bounding box that shows the dimensions of the complete voxel grid in passed color
:param voxel_grid: The voxel grid used to draw the bounding box
:return: None
'''
# Drawing lines parallel to x axis
sense_change_z = 0
for z_step in range(2):
    sense_change_y = 0
    for y_step in range(2):
        if sense_change_y == 0:
            xs = [voxel_grid.min_grid_x - voxel_grid.min_grid_x, voxel_grid.max_grid_x - voxel_grid.min_grid_x]
            sense_change_y = 1
        else:
            xs = [voxel_grid.max_grid_x - voxel_grid.min_grid_x, voxel_grid.min_grid_x - voxel_grid.min_grid_x]
            sense_change_y = 0
        if y_step == 0:
            y_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_y
        else:
            y_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_y
        if z_step == 0:
            z_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_z
        else:
            z_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_z
        ys = [y_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_y, y_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_y]
        zs = [z_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_z, z_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_z]
        mlab.plot3d(xs, ys, zs, color=color, tube_radius=tube_radius)
# Drawing lines parallel to y axis
for x_step in range(2):
    for z_step in range(2):
        ys = [voxel_grid.min_grid_y - voxel_grid.min_grid_y, voxel_grid.max_grid_y - voxel_grid.min_grid_y]
        if x_step == 0:
            x_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_x
        else:
            x_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_x
        if z_step == 0:
            z_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_z
        else:
            z_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_z
        xs = [x_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_x, x_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_x]
        zs = [z_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_z, z_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_z]
        mlab.plot3d(xs, ys, zs, color=color, tube_radius=tube_radius)
# Drawing lines parallel to z axis
for x_step in range(2):
    for y_step in range(2):
        zs = [voxel_grid.min_grid_z - voxel_grid.min_grid_z, voxel_grid.max_grid_z - voxel_grid.min_grid_z]
        if x_step == 0:
            x_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_x
        else:
            x_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_x
        if y_step == 0:
            y_coord = voxel_grid.min_grid_y
        else:
            y_coord = voxel_grid.max_grid_y
        xs = [x_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_x, x_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_x]
        ys = [y_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_y, y_coord - voxel_grid.min_grid_y]
        mlab.plot3d(xs, ys, zs, color=color, tube_radius=tube_radius)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting arbitrary lines between points with one call of points3d is possible and extremely fast. Use following code from the [protein example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_protein.html)

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

connections = ((0,2),(3,5)) # point 0 and 2 and 3 and 5 are connected
x = np.random.randn(10)
y = np.random.randn(10)
z = np.random.randn(10)
pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z)

pts.mlab_source.dataset.lines = np.array(connections)

tube = mlab.pipeline.tube(pts, tube_radius=0.15)
tube.filter.radius_factor = 1.
mlab.pipeline.surface(tube, color=(0.8, 0.8, 0))

mlab.show()
```

Comment: Thank you..! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @luigui2906 if you like my answer please accept and upvote it

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same situation. Finally, I use `mlab.quiver3d` to solve this problem. Here is my [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356371/how-to-draw-disconnected-lines-in-mayavi-and-customize-their-colors-without-loop/77357613#77357613). Not only is it simpler and fast, but you can control the color of each line segmention individually! (In the code of this solution, I can assign the color of each box.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jannick for the answer.

Here is the new function in case someone is interested:

```
def draw_voxel_grid_cells(voxel_grid):

# Array for the points with the shape of the total number of points needed to define for drawing all the lines of the grid
points = np.zeros((((voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1) + (voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1) + (voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1))*2, 3))
i = 0
# Drawing lines parallel to x axis
for z_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1):
    for y_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1):
        points[i,:]    = [voxel_grid.min_grid_x, voxel_grid.min_grid_y+(voxel_grid.resolution*y_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_z+(voxel_grid.resolution*z_step)]
        points[i+1, :] = [voxel_grid.max_grid_x, voxel_grid.min_grid_y+(voxel_grid.resolution*y_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_z+(voxel_grid.resolution*z_step)]
        i += 2
# Drawing lines parallel to y axis
for z_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1):
    for x_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1):
        points[i,:]    = [voxel_grid.min_grid_x+(voxel_grid.resolution*x_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_y, voxel_grid.min_grid_z+(voxel_grid.resolution*z_step)]
        points[i+1, :] = [voxel_grid.min_grid_x+(voxel_grid.resolution*x_step), voxel_grid.max_grid_y, voxel_grid.min_grid_z+(voxel_grid.resolution*z_step)]
        i += 2
# Drawing lines parallel to z axis
for y_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1):
    for x_step in range(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1):
        points[i,:] =    [voxel_grid.min_grid_x+(voxel_grid.resolution*x_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_y+(voxel_grid.resolution*y_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_z]
        points[i+1, :] = [voxel_grid.min_grid_x+(voxel_grid.resolution*x_step), voxel_grid.min_grid_y+(voxel_grid.resolution*y_step), voxel_grid.max_grid_z]
        i += 2
connections = np.arange(0, ((voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1) + (voxel_grid.nbr_cells_z+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1) + (voxel_grid.nbr_cells_y+1)*(voxel_grid.nbr_cells_x+1))*2)
connections = tuple(connections.reshape(-1,2))

# Plotting -------------------------------------------------
mlab.figure()
pts = mlab.points3d(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], scale_factor=0.0001, color=(1, 0, 0))
pts.mlab_source.dataset.lines = np.array(connections)
tube = mlab.pipeline.tube(pts, tube_radius=0.001)
tube.filter.radius_factor = 1.
mlab.pipeline.surface(tube, color=(1, 0, 0))
mlab.show()
# ----------------------------------------------------------

return
```